# How to disable back button When ActivityIndicator Is Running

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using **Xamrin.forms** PLC Project,
So,I am trying to disable back button when Activity Indicator is Running then I will enable back button when Activity Indicator is finished.
this is My Code:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
 {
   activityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
   activityIndicator.IsVisible = true;
   //I need to disable back button here
   activityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
   activityIndicator.IsVisible = false;
   //I need to enable back button here     
 }
```

Comment: **Please note** that you can *bind* `activiityIndicator.IsRunning` and `activityIndicator.IsVisible` to `Page.IsBusy`when you're within a page. This can make to code a bit cleaner.

Comment: could you please add some code,it is nice idea also ..thanks

Comment: `<ActivityIndicator IsVisible="{Binding Source=MyPage, Path=IsBusy}" IsRunning="true">...` - since we do not show the activity indicator when it's not running, we can set the `IsRunning` property to true.

Comment: You have to set the `x:Name="MyPage"` attribute accordingly in your page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the static `NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton` method (See [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton/p/Xamarin.Forms.Page/System.Boolean/)) to hide the *back button* of your page.

Furthermore you can override `OnBackButtonPressed`

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    if(activityIndicator.IsRunning = true)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

(see [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/177042/#Comment_177042)) to prevent going back when the user presses the hardware back button.